# Solving recuurence equation $T(n)=3T(n/2)+cn$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Please check my solving process.

Using recursion tree method for $T(n)=3T(n/2)+cn$,

\begin{align}
T(n)&=\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2 n}\frac{3^i}{2^i}cn\\
&=cn\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2 n}(\frac{3^i}{2^i})\\
&=cn\frac{(\frac{3}{2})^{{\log_2 n}+1}-1}{\frac{3}{2}-1}\\
&=cn\frac{(\frac{3}{2})^{{\log_2 n}+1}-1}{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=2cn(\frac{3}{2})^{{\log_2 n}+1}-2cn\\
&=2cn(\frac{3^{\log_2 n}}{n})-2cn\\
&=6c3^{{\log_2 n}+1}-2cn\\
&\approx6c3^{{\log_2 n}+1}\\
&=\theta(n^{\log_2 3})
\end{align}

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

actually we get the following solution $$T(n)=c_1 3^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}-1}-2 c
   \left(n-3^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}}\right)$$

Comment: What is c1 and c? I don't know how this equation derived.

Comment: $$c_1$$ is a constant, and $$c$$ is in your equation above

Comment: You mean I'm wrong?

Comment: the solution can be written as $$T(n)=(6c+c_1)3^{\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}}-2cn$$

Comment: compare your solution with the solution above!

Comment: I edited, plz check